# A set theoretic question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement true?

If a nonempty collection $\mathcal{A}$ of sets is closed under countable union, it is also closed under finite union.

---

My guess is it is not true unless $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$, but I don't know where to look for a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Let $A_1, ..., A_k$ be a finite collection of sets of $\mathcal{A}$.  Set $A_{k + j} = A_k$ for $j \ge 1$.  Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} A_n$

Comment: Thank you. My guess was wrong!